# Is it possible to make React-like compound components in lit 2.0?

Tags: web-component, lit-element, lit-html, lit

I tried to build compound components with Lit 2.0 but passing data to slots as attributes seems impossible.

```
  <my-accordion>
    <my-accordion-title>Title</my-accordion-title>
    <my-accordion-content>Content</my-accordion-content>
  </my-accordion
```

How I can pass "extended" propery to custom elements slots?

Here is my custom elements:

```
@customElement("my-accordion")
export class MyAccordion extends LitElement {

  @property()
  extended: boolean = false;

  toggleExtend(){
     this.extended = !this.extended
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div @click=${this.toggleExtend}>
        <slot .extended=${this.extended}></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}


@customElement("my-accordion-title")
export class MyAccordionTitle extends LitElement {
  // want to access parent node extended property here
  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doable in Lit, but shorter in Vanilla: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/acme-the-accordion-web-component-in-187-bytes-47ah

Comment: Thanks! it is a great suggestion but as i know summary and details not supported in IE 11.  https://caniuse.com/?search=summary%2Cdetails

Comment: If you need IE11 support (while even Microsoft says its a security risk) You are heading for way more trouble... Please, next time, add that IE requirement to your question, saves us from having to read it, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the `extended` property to slotted children, get the slot element's `assignedElements()` array.

```js
@customElement("my-accordion")
export class MyAccordion extends LitElement {

  @property()
  extended: boolean = false;

  toggleExtend(){
     this.extended = !this.extended
  }

  updated(changed: PropertyValues<this>) {
    if (changed.has('extended'))
      this.extendedChanged()
  }

  extendedChanged() {
    for (const child of this.slot.assignedElements()) {
      if (child instanceof MyAccordionTitle)
        child.extended = this.extended;
    }
  }

  @query('slot') slot: HTMLSlotElement | null;
  
  render() {
    return html`
      <div @click=${this.toggleExtend}>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}


@customElement("my-accordion-title")
export class MyAccordionTitle extends LitElement {
  // want to access parent node extended property here
  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
```

NB: When assigning click listeners to `<div>` and other non-interactive elements, there are many accessibility issues involved. It's usually recommended therefore to use a `<button>` element, or in your case maybe a `<details>` and `<summary>`

Comment: Note that Lit 2 in Typescript now has [`@queryAssignedNodes`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#query-assigned-nodes)

Comment: I was actually gonna recommend that but couldn't see immediately from the docs how to do an anonymous slot, but with a filter. `@queryAssignedNodes(undefined, undefined, 'my-accordion-title')`?